# System variable change doesn't work

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm going to change a system variable in mysql by:

```
mysql -u root -e "set collation_connection=utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
```

but when i call the following command it is not changed:

```
mysql -u root -e "select @@collation_connection"
```

I even restart the mysql service but it doesn't work.

Comment: You either need `set global collation_connection` or `set persist collation_connection` or `set @@collation_connection`

Comment: to add to @Nick 's comment `persist` keyword only works in MySQL 8.0+